# ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID with wildcard certificate with Apache

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, certificate, https

I'm new to managing SSL certificates so my problem might be simple to resolve. I'm trying to add my wildcard SSL certificate to my website hosted on a container running Apache on Azure Container Service.

My wildcard certificate was in a `.pfx` format so the first thing I did was to transform it to `.cer` and `.key` files following the steps [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774574/how-can-i-convert-a-pfx-certificate-file-for-use-with-apache-on-a-linux-server).

Then, in my container running apache, I modified the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf`. Resulting `default-ssl.conf` file looks like this (I just modified the path of the SSLCertificate and SSLCertificateKeyFile parameters):

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

            DocumentRoot /var/www

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

            SSLEngine on

            SSLCertificateFile    /path/to/my_cert.cer
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/my_cert.key

            <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </FilesMatch>
            <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I reloaded apache with `service apache2 reload` and tried accessing my website using https, but I'm getting the error:

`NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`

```
Subject: *.mywildcarddomain.com

Issuer: COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA

Expires on: 23 janv. 2019

Current date: 5 avr. 2018

PEM encoded chain:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFYDCCBEigAwIBAgIQa+Poznv/97OzNsLOXAg7XzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCB
kDELMAkGA1UEBhMCR0IxGzAZBgNVBAgTEkdyZWF0ZXIgTWFuY2hlc3RlcjEQMA4G
[...]
ABtyht+psnih978xFzBZcAJVWFkbJI2AAOJudMkquV7z1OdmR9jHfPPLMGa7OZf0
4AzQWsxBGuRgoAGGyL3NluVcbrYldc/O/A4jbJDaywjWkpPn
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGCDCCA/CgAwIBAgIQKy5u6tl1NmwUim7bo3yMBzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQwFADCB
hTELMAkGA1UEBhMCR0IxGzAZBgNVBAgTEkdyZWF0ZXIgTWFuY2hlc3RlcjEQMA4G
[...]
lBlGGSW4gNfL1IYoakRwJiNiqZ+Gb7+6kHDSVneFeO/qJakXzlByjAA6quPbYzSf
+AZxAeKCINT+b72x
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIF2DCCA8CgAwIBAgIQTKr5yttjb+Af907YWwOGnTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQwFADCB
hTELMAkGA1UEBhMCR0IxGzAZBgNVBAgTEkdyZWF0ZXIgTWFuY2hlc3RlcjEQMA4G
[...]
0MC2Hb46TpSi125sC8KKfPog88Tk5c0NqMuRkrF8hey1FGlmDoLnzc7ILaZRfyHB
NVOFBkpdn627G190
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I tried accessing the website using the Azure URL (i.e.: https://mysite-agents.canadaeast.cloudapp.azure.com).

Am I missing configuration in another file ? What have I done wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. I just mapped `mywebsite.mywildcarddomain.com` to my azure website and now I can access with https.